Adjust left margin of whole paragraph
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=1.5cm,
  right=1.5cm,
  top=1.5cm,
  bottom=1.5cm
}

\newfontfamily\DVLight[]{DejaVuSans-ExtraLight}

\newcommand\textrmlf[1]{{\DVLight#1}}

\definecolor{gray94}{HTML}{f0f0f0}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.375\textwidth}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
      grow to left by = 0.6325cm,
      colback = gray94,
      frame hidden,
      boxrule = 0pt,
      arc = 0mm]

    \begin{scriptsize}
        \hspace*{-1cm}
        \begin{flushleft}
              \hspace*{-1cm}
        \textrmlf {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
        placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
        dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,
        nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
        magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
        senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
        turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
        metus rhoncus sem}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{scriptsize}
    
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}

The flushleft environment serves to compact the line spacing in this paragraph, which is otherwise unsightly. However, this linespacing also goes away without the flushleft provided I do not set textrmlf.
But the thing that I specifically want to address is the fact that the hspace* command isn't shifting the block of text left. I need it shifted left to bring it into alignment with many single lines of text used throughout the tcolorbox, each of which is currently brought closer to the left edge of the box by means of the hspace* command with negative values. My reasoning was that hopefully, hspace* just before a flushleft environment would shift the whole environment over. Instead, no effect.
I have included an additional hspace* command within the flushleft environment to illustrate that all this achieves is moving the first line to the left, leaving the rest of the paragraph untouched.
More generally, I would be interested in any solution for vertically or horizontally shifting 'blocks' within the document such that all text (and graphics) within them are moved accordingly: right now in my novice approach I am using hspace* on individual lines and vspace* between them in a way I cannot imagine is the intended path.

Welcome! Please give a complete example starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document} that can be compiled and tested directly.

scriptsize is not an environment.

You probably don't want to put a tcolorbox into a minipage or flushleft into tcolorbox. But it's going to be hard for anybody to suggest more than generalisations without knowing what's responsible for the alignment you want to change.

I guess this is a kind of XY-problem and removing of the extra margin can be done different, if you would show the tcolorbox you really have, and complete the code with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Please post a complete code here. Links to external pages are frowned upon as your question will become meaningless when the link disappears (next week,  next month, next year...).

Possible duplicate: Indenting a whole paragraph

I'd start by using a fixed value for \leftskip, bounded by \begingroup ... \par \endgroup as shown in the answer by Daniel to the "possible duplicate" question cited by @Werner.

Sorry, it is not clear what you after:

Does tcolorbox is obligatory?
In which direction it should be moved?

In MWE below are two examples (based on pure guessing). The first is with tcolorbox, the second without it. The both are shifted to the right:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\DVLight[]{DejaVuSans-ExtraLight}
    \newcommand\textrmlf[1]{{\DVLight#1}}
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
    \definecolor{gray94}{HTML}{f0f0f0}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\hspace*{0.6325cm}\begin{minipage}{.375\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth,
                  fontupper=\textrmlf\scriptsize,
                  halign=flush left,
      colback = gray94,
      frame hidden,
      boxrule = 0pt,
      arc = 0mm
      ]
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
        placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
        dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,
        nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
        magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
        senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
        turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
        metus rhoncus sem.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[66]

\hspace*{0.6325cm}\begin{minipage}{.375\textwidth}\raggedright
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
        placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
        dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,
        nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
        magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
        senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
        turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
        metus rhoncus sem.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


